# How to hold a long calculated string in recordset just by sql query?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, recordset

I need fetch data from an MS Access database using a SQL query in a VB program.

The result is stored in a recordset, one of the fields is `f100`, it's calculated by connecting multiple strings.

If the length of `f100`'s value is less than 255, the result is correct, but if it's longer than 255, the result is wrong: `f100` just remains 255 characters in length and subsequent characters disappear.

My SQL statement is like this:

```
Select iif(f1=1,'123','')+iif(f2=1,'456','')+...... as f100 from Table1
```

My program is like this:

```
Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strConn$, strSQL$
strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\try.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"
Conn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
Conn.Open strConn
strSQL="Select iif(f1=1,'123','')+iif(f2=1,'456','')+...... as f100 from Table1"
With rst
.CursorType = adOpenStatic
.LockType = adLockOptimistic
.CursorLocation = adUseClient
.Open strSQL, Conn
End With

'here rst.fields("f100") remains a max of 255 char
'debug.print rst.fields("f100")

rst.Close
Conn.Close
```

Is there any solution that hold a long calculated string in recordset just by SQL query?

Comment: Possible duplicate. Have you verified the actual length of string using the len() function? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927042/concatenation-and-max-length-of-string-in-vba-access

Comment: Yes, I have verified that, If I open a .mdb file and run the query statement  in Access, the result is correct. If I fill data to recordset by the same query statement in programming environment, the result is wrong.